# iptables - ignoring -i

Tags: linux, iptables

In my iptables rules, I want to accept only lo but drop every other interface.
but when I execute this command :
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

it is not specifying interface lo but it is accepting all interfaces. 
Any suggestion ?

is ignoring the interface and

```
# iptables --flush
# iptables-restore /tmp/h 
# iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain bad_packets (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain bad_tcp_packets (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain icmp_packets (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain tcp_inbound (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain tcp_outbound (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain udp_inbound (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain udp_outbound (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
# cat /tmp/h 
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.18 on Thu Jan  1 08:47:28 1970
*filter
:INPUT DROP [53:20507]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:bad_packets - [0:0]
:bad_tcp_packets - [0:0]
:icmp_packets - [0:0]
:tcp_inbound - [0:0]
:tcp_outbound - [0:0]
:udp_inbound - [0:0]
:udp_outbound - [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Jan  1 08:47:28 1970
```

--- on another note : flush is not changing the default policy

```
# iptables --flush
# iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Use the `-v` option when listing your firewall rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like iptables -nvL to include interface name.

Comment: 'Chain INPUT (policy DROP) ' does that mean it drops all packets ? It is not dropping for me. Iam able to telnet into the box that has this rule.

Comment: That could be because traffic goes through the FORWARD chain or INPUT chain has an ACCEPT rule.

Comment: but you can see from my iptables --list the policy is DROP for both ? is it a bug in my platform ( mine is an embedded linux soc).

Comment: also, iptables --flush is not changing the default policy from DROP to Accept

Comment: It isn't supposed to; `--flush` deletes all the rules in a chain, it has nothing to do with policy.